# File Name Not Changing in Database but Changing in Assets folder in file upload of Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

my model

public function saveProduct(
$name,
$cat_id,
$user_id,
$description,
$status
) {
$post_image = '';

```
    if (array_key_exists('post_image', $_FILES)) {
        $config = [];

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/products';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|svg|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('post_image')) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {

            $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
            
        }
    }

    $data = [
        'name' => $name,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'cat_id' => $cat_id,
        'description' => $description,
        'status' => 'active'
    ];

    if ($post_image) {
        $data['post_image'] = $post_image;
    }


    $this->db->insert('p0_products', $data);
    return true;
}
```

it is changing file name to encryption in folder but in mysql i'am getting file name same as old name with unchanged on non-encrypted format

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're taking from $_FILES veriable. You should take from

> $this->upload->data()

So how?

> $fileData = $this->upload->data();

This will return

1. file_name
2. file_type
3. file_path
   etc.

> $fileName = $fileData['file_name']